# Why mention possessions in Al Hanisim

Tags: tefilla, purim

The Al Hanisim for Purim mentions Haman's plot to kill every single Jew. However the list of victims ends with a seemingly unnecessary point that not only will they be killed, but their possessions taken for plunder.

> בִּקֵּשׁ לְהַשְׁמִיד לַהֲרוג וּלְאַבֵּד אֶת כָּל הַיְּהוּדִים מִנַּעַר וְעַד זָקֵן טַף וְנָשִׁים בְּיום אֶחָד. בִּשְׁלשָׁה עָשר לְחדֶשׁ שְׁנֵים עָשר. הוּא חדֶשׁ אֲדָר. **וּשְׁלָלָם לָבוז**:
>
> when he sought to destroy, murder, and to eliminate all the Jews, from the young to the old, infants and women, in one day, on the thirteenth of the twelfth month of Adar, and **plunder their wealth**.

Seems disconnected from the immediately preceding statement, the date of the plot, as well as redundant since everyone is dead. Why is this mentioned?

Comment: When I think of the holocaust, the fact that anti-semities immediately  plundered the possesions of those murdered makes it worse

Comment: @Schmerel, not merely in the Shoah. Every scapegoated group (especially us) have faced the plundering of their valuables the moment it becomes acceptable. Hell, even our people have done it when Hashem hasn't permitted taking treasure !

Comment: See also:  ולקחת אותנו לעבדים ואת חמורינו.   Who cares about the donkeys if they're going to be enslaved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it's quoting the verse (Esther 3:13), so it makes sense to quote the whole thing, which ends with וּשְׁלָלָם לָבוז.

Answer (score 0):

reb Galeeko. on megillah 3/13......

says that the reason posuk ends with the words
“ushlullum luvoiz “
it shows that haman wanted them to kill
with hatred ,merciless  and speed 
so he promised them $$$$

(same like paroh in mitzrayim)

possible that answers your question!!!
because what we are saying with those words ......
is haman hated us (and as the GRA says on purim we want to remember the tzara because that itself was the salvation)so much as we see from those words .......yet hash-em saved us by doing 
ונהפוך הוא

p.s.
it also was his downfall
because it proves what esther said......
kee ein hatzurrr shove binezekk hamelech